# Pass PHP Array to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Am trying to pass an array of values from PHP function to Javascript. Not sure if I am doing it correctly.

PHP:

```
function toggleLayers(){
    for($i=0;$i<$group_layer_row;$i++){
        $toggleArray=mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
        return $toggleArray;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
var myArray = [JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($toggleArray); ?>")];
    for(var i=0;i < myArray.length; i++){
        if($myArray.getVisibility()==true){
            $myArray.getVisibility(false);
        }
    else{
        $myArray.getVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

SQL (for reference):

```
$con = mssql_connect("myServer", "myUsername", myPassword");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM m_group_layer WHERE group_id=\"".$_SESSION["group_id"]."\" ORDER BY display_order";
$rs_group_layer = mssql_query ($sql, $con);   
$group_layer_row = mssql_num_rows($rs_group_layer);
```

I have been looking at some other similar questions, and the answers are either vague and/or there are a few thousand of them.

Would appreciate any help, also please try to explain as if you were writing a book called "Idiot's Guide to Passing PHP Arrays to JS"

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

Sorry, my question was very vague. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1.PHP Function gets all records from table into array(in this case they are map layers)

2.Javascript receives PHP array and loops through adding if clause to toggle layers.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Does it work? What doesn't work?

Comment: It does not work.. it keeps giving me a [JSON.parse("null")] statement and Object doesn't support property or method 'getVisibility'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than you think.

Change this line:

```
var myArray = [JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($toggleArray); ?>")];
```

To just:

```
var myArray = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($toggleArray), ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>;
```

`json_encode` produces a json string. Echoing the string into a javascript context is the equivalent of a javascript literal. The `htmlspecialchars` is just for the necessary html escaping and is not unique to echoing json.

**NOTE** however that you can only json_encode a php object or array, not any scalar types like ints or strings. This is a limitation of JSON itself.  In your `toggleLayers()` function, you are returning a string, not an array.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I don't think you can insert php tags into a JS script like that...

Comment: Then the problem with your code is not in the json layer, but in the php layer. Your php array is being prepared incorrectly. I added an explanation of your `toggleLayers()` problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a code I received recently and was asked to work on, half of it I am still trying to understand why the original programmer made it this way...

Comment: Ahh..that's true... but I can't change the values of the array to string after I've already passed it to the JS function...

Comment: All this code is so full of errors that we can't fix it without rewriting every line. But the answer to your question "how pass a php array into javascript" is answered.

Answer (score -5):

A thing that would be very useful to understand:

You sumply **can't** "pass an array of values from PHP function to Javascript".
But rather you have to **create the javascript code** using PHP just like you are creating HTML.

Thus, 3 simple step to solve **any** problem with PHP -> client transfers:

1. Create a pure client-side code you wish. Make it work. Save it somewhere.
2. Create a PHP code to produce that client-side code.
3. Compare the codes. If doesn't match - correct the PHP code. Repeat until done.